# Cant boot Ubuntu Server 18.04 on HP 4530s after successful installation

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, hp, bootloader

The laptop i am using is HP Probook 4530s
*Config*
Intel Core i3 (2nd Gen) 2310M / 2.1 GHz
3GB RAM
320 HDD

I am trying install ubuntu server 18.04 on it. But after successful installation it wont boot,it shows

```
Boot Device Not Found
Please install an operating system on harddisk.
Hard Disk - 3F0
```

Thinking that its a HDD/Installation problem i installed i windows 7 and it worked perfectly fine.To test i installed (dual boot) Ubuntu 18.04(Not server) and now i can dual boot windows and Ubuntu.

After all this steps i installed Ubuntu Server again it wont detect the partitions, but as a single drive (i can partition of-course ) but the old drives are not showing there. So i install it again, **but it wont BOOT, same error message.**

I tried searching but didn't find anything , that's why i am posting here. 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

NB: I also tried booting live and run boot-repair but it didn't fix.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the boot flag using Gparted or any other partition manager using Live Boot USB. You system is unable to find the boot flag on any partition on the hard disk to boot from.

PS: Since I was unable to comment, I am writing here. Will improve it later.